# Beamer: \appendix to add extra slides produces warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string

Tags: beamer, hyperref, appendices, warnings

I am re-running an old Beamer presentation with TexLive 2017, and the command `\appendix` produces a warning that it did not use to produce, though it does work properly:

> Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing
>   `\translate '

See the following MWE. How can I get rid of that warning? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{AnnArbor}
    \usecolortheme{wolverine}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
slide 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
slide 3
\end{frame}

\appendix %do not count the following slides for the total number

\begin{frame}
extra slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
extra slide 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/449

Comment: please not that `\appendix` is not from the `appendixnumberbeamer` package, but from beamer itself

Comment: Isn't it? It only works when I add `\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}`... So there is not a fix at the moment? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround:

```
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{\texorpdfstring{\translate{Appendix}}{Appendix}}
```

In fact, if your beamer version is resonable up-to-date, you don't need the `appendixnumberbeamer` to modify the frame numbering but you can use `\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{AnnArbor}
    \usecolortheme{wolverine}
    \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[appendixframenumber]
}

\renewcommand{\appendixname}{\texorpdfstring{\translate{Appendix}}{Appendix}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
slide 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
slide 3
\end{frame}

\appendix %do not count the following slides for the total number

\begin{frame}
extra slide 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
extra slide 2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to make it work with my custom theme (while `\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}` + `\appendix` does work, despite the warning)... Is there anything known to clash with it that I might be loading in my theme? I get no errors or warnings, it just does not work with my theme (as in numbering goes from the first to the very last slide)

Comment: @DaniCee It depends on the definition of your footline. If it uses `page number in head/foot` template it will work, otherwise not. But this is entirely unrelated to your `appendix+warning` problem.

Comment: OK it does work perfect without warnings if I do `\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}` instead of `\setbeamertemplate{page number...` and then `\renewcommand{\appendixname...`